# Salesforce Web-to-lead issue with posting phone number

Tags: salesforce

I've tried each of the variations below and get the following error,

*Salesforce could not create this lead because of the reason listed below. For more information about this error or help with Web-to-Lead, please contact Customer Support.
Reason: Only Numbers are allowed in Phone number.*

I'm only using numbers so I'm not sure what the issue is. My coding is very limited, but I feel like this should be an easy fix.

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="phoneNumber" />

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="Number" />

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" />

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" />

Comment: I found this in a validation rule for the phone field.

NOT( REGEX( Phone , "^[0-9]*"))

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Salesforce is relaxed about phone numbers. They're essentially Text(40) fields, you can put + signs, spaces, extensions...

Your administrator has put a validation rule on the field that throws when there are any characters other than 0-9 range. (There might be more code validations hidden, you'd need to check debug logs)

What are you entering? The way this validation's written I think it'll also throw if the field is blank.

Comment: I moved this to the salesforce SO as I thought it would be a better fit. But to answer the question, I've tried 111-555-4444 as well as 1115554444.